# Delegated Authentication for Mobile Users in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on

Why is delegated Authentication recommended for SSO configuration for Mobile users in salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is because DelAuth is the **only** SSO method that SFDC has enabled for their mobile application...so you really don't have a choice. I would expect SFDC to move to a standards-based model eventually.